# Android and Python different SHA1 checksum of the same file

Tags: android, python, sha1, checksum, sha

The scenario is the next:

I want to upload image to the server. But before uploading the file I have to send the `SHA1` checksum of that file so the server could check if the file is already uploaded so I don't upload it again.

The problem is that for the same file I don't get the same `SHA1` checksum in my app and on the server side.

Here is the code in my Android app:

```
public static String getSHA1FromFileContent(String filename)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {

    final MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    for (int read = 0; (read = is.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
        messageDigest.update(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    is.close();

    // Convert the byte to hex format
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();

    for (final byte b : messageDigest.digest()) {
        formatter.format("%02x", b);
    }

    String res = formatter.toString();

    formatter.close();

    return res;
}
```

And here is the code on the server side:

```
def hashFile(f):

sha1 = hashlib.sha1()

if hasattr(f, 'multiple_chunks') and f.multiple_chunks():
    for c in f.chunks():
    sha1.update(c)
else:
    try:
    sha1.update(f.read())
    finally:
    f.close()

return sha1.hexdigest()
```

What is the problem and why do I get different `SHA1` checksums?

Comment: How do you open the file on the server side? Possibly you need to open in binary mode to avoid line-end conversion

Comment: I don't write the server side code, but I got answer that this is already handled :) Also they don't have problem in generating the same SHA1 from javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out there was some server side image editing before generating the `sha1` sum that wasn't meant to be done in this scenario. They made changes on the server side and now this is working perfectly.